# What does "=~" do in the bash shell of linux

Tags: linux, bash

As the title said what does the "=~" do in the bash shell script running on Linux? I googled online and found that "==" checks equality and "!=" checks inequality. How about "=~"? I guess it may be some regular expression matching?

Comment: Why guess instead of just reading the documentation?

Comment: Have not found the documentation. Googled and did not find the answer.

Comment: What do you see if you google "bash manual"? Anyway, I gave you a link in my answer, bookmark it.

Answer (score 5):

The `=~` does a bash [regular expression match](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html)

**Example**

```
$ [[ 45 =~ [0-9]+ ]] && echo "45 contains digits"
45 contains digits

$ [[ "hello" =~ [0-9]+ ]] && echo "hello doesnt contains digits"
$ [[ "hello" =~ [a-z]+ ]] && echo "hello contains alphabets"
hello contains alphabets
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's regular expression matching. It's in the `bash` [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> An additional binary operator, `=~`, is available, with the same precedence as `==` and `!=`. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in *regex3*)).

Comment: What is "regex3"?

Comment: @rwols I think they meant `regex(3)` -- the number in parentheses refers to the section of the Unix manual on library functions.

Comment: @rwols  you must read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577364/how-to-match-a-something-or-nothing-in-a-bash-regex   it s better to get shocked now than later...